# MySQL multi-search with jQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have designed a form that allows the user to input Name, region, age and language. I've also made a PHP script that gets the data that they input, however if the user leaves a field empty or they started to write in name and deleted it the database returns every field because it matches every record in the database. Is there a way to dis-include empty fields? If someone could do name and region I should be able to figure out the rest. I have the jQuery and AJAX set up so that if a keypress is done in any of the form, it performs this searchFunction. I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing the MySQL than what I'm doing. After looking at the first answer and trying to implement it, I'm not sure on how to update the MySQL if the variable is not set unless I do 20+ if else statements.

ajax:

```
$(function() {
                $("#searchform").bind('submit',function() {
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var region =$('#region').val();
                    $.get('scripts/searchFunction.php',{name:name, region:region}, function(data){
                        $("#show").html(data);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                $("#searchform").keyup(function() {
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var region =$('#region').val();
                    $.get('scripts/searchFunction.php',{name:name, region:region}, function(data){
                        $("#show").html(data);
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

searchFunction.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
session_start();
$name = "%" . $_GET['name'] . "%";
$region = "%" . $_GET['region'] . "%";
$dbuname;
$dbfname;
$dblname;
$dbage;
$dbregion;
$dblanguage;

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Region, Language FROM '. $table .' WHERE First_Name LIKE ? OR Region LIKE ?;');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$name, $region);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($dbuname, $dbfname, $dblname, $dbage, $dbregion, $dblanguage);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
    if(file_exists("../img/accounts/" .$dbuname . "/Profile.jpg")){
        echo '<img src="img/accounts/'. $dbuname .'/Profile.jpg" class="img-fixed"/>';
    }else if(file_exists('../img/accounts/' .$dbuname . '/Profile.png"')){
        echo '<img src="img/accounts/'. $dbuname .'/Profile.png"/>';
    }else{
        echo '<img src="img/default-img/default.png" class="img-fixed"/>';    
    }

    echo '</div>';    

    echo '<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">';
    echo '<p>First Name: ' . $dbfname . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Last Name: ' . $dblname . '</p>';
    if(isset($_SESSION['Loggedin'])){
        if($_SESSION['Loggedin'] == 1){
            echo '<p>Age: ' . $dbage . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Region: ' . $dbregion . '</p>'; 
            echo '<p>Language: ' . $dblanguage . '</p>';
        }
    } 
    echo '</div>';    
    echo '</div>';    
    echo '<hr class="section-spacer"/>';  
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a validation before `ajax` call and check if user has entered anything (other than a space), e.g.:

```
var str = $('#field').val();
if(val && val.trim().length > 0){
  //method call
}
```

This way, function won't be called if input is null or contains whitespaces only.

**Update**

You need to modify the php code to create and run the query dynamically based on passed parameters, e.g:

```
$stmt;
if (!empty($name) and !empty($region)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Region, Language FROM '. $table .' WHERE First_Name LIKE ? OR Region LIKE ?;');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$name, $region);
}else if (!empty($name)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Region, Language FROM '. $table .' WHERE First_Name LIKE ?;');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$name);
}else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Region, Language FROM '. $table .' WHERE Region LIKE ?;');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$region);
}
```

Comment: I've added the Ajax from my code, would it be able to work in the example above? Because I have two functions, one for submit and one for keyup

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap the `get` function call inside `if` condition like the one I showed in the example.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to use $.get or switch it out and use an array with $.ajax and use data:data?

Comment: Yes, it'll be good to extract out the code and move it to a separate function.

Comment: Okay, I got the jist now. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Oh hang on, how do I update the query tho? So let's say that they decide to only have the region and age, how would I reflect the MySQL so that it does WHERE Region LIKE % $region %

Comment: You can pass another parameter to function which denotes which field to query. Like `field` and add an `if` condition based on that.

Comment: This causes an error though with the prepared statements. I've also tried "SELECT Username, First_Name, Last_Name, Age, Region, Language FROM '. $table .' WHERE First_Name LIKE ? OR Region" But as I said since first_name is not set it assumes it's blank and thus just returns every entry in the database

Comment: @Chromatic I have updated my answer, could you please have a look at the php code?

Comment: That has worked :) Thank you again! I'm sorry for making you write out the example but I reassure you that I have learnt something from your methodology. I'm still new to prepared statement and I do appreciate the time you spent to build that example. I'll manipulate it to now match the rest of my database.

Comment: No worries mate.. Glad that I could help you learn something new.